# Icon aligns to center when using display: table and margin: auto, but when I change to display:none it does not align to center after .show()

Tags: javascript, html, css

This works and properly aligns the icons:

```
#stepSuccess {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
#stepFailure {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here are the icons themselves:

```
<i class='icon-ok icon-4x icon-green'id='stepSuccess'></i>
<i class='icon-remove icon-4x icon-red'id='stepFailure'></i>
```

However, I need it to be at display: none for javascript purposes.  When I try the code below it does not align to the center after I use .show() to display the icon.

```
#stepSuccess {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#stepFailure {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the jQuery

```
if(checked)
            {
                //display correct-answer dialogue
                $("#stepSuccess").show();
            {
else
            {
                //display wrong-answer dialogue
                $("#stepFailure").show();
            }
```

How do I keep display: none and still have the code properly align to the center of the div (after .show() in javascript)? I also tried text-align: center;

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for reference, post your jQuery code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that when you use `.show()`, it sets `display: inline` instead of `display: table`.  Instead of `.show()`, I would set up two classes, one for show and one for hide, and toggle the class.

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
if(checked)
            {
                //display correct-answer dialogue
                $("#stepSuccess").css('display','table');

            {
else
            {
                //display wrong-answer dialogue
                $("#stepFailure").css('display','table');
            }
```

instead of `.show()`.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help.  I adjusted my question to properly display my problem.  I am basically choosing between two icons depending upon the return of true or false from a function - so I am not quite sure how to use .toggleClass or .css given this problem

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of less code, would you be able to just set the opacity to 0, rather than hide?